# svnadmin dump reports error but verify does not

Tags: svn

The message for *svnadmin dump* is *svnadmin: malformed file*. However *svnadmin verify* does not report any errors at all. I searched through a few backups and did a binary comparison of the repositories with winmerge (which is binary and actually compares the contents, not just the file dates). In my backup that was made 1 day after the revision was created I did not find any differences. So I don't think the file became corrupted on disk over time.
So what can I do now? Btw, this is certainly a bug in SVN because verfiy does not find the error.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the issue you have described, because I use FSFS rather than BDB as long as I can identify where the corruption has occurred I can edit the text files to correct the inconsistency, this has worked for `svnadmin verify` positive and negative corruption.

I host Subversion through Apache with mod_dav_svn, more than once it has been suggested that it could be an Apache threading issue.

Comment: I opened the text file but I do not know what inconsistency is present. It must be like a single bit because it looks ok. It is not complete garbage.

Comment: The times it has happened to me it has been glaring, i.e. the revision field that should contain a number containing a date, or a date field set to 1970-01-01.